# is it possible using Firebase Storage to make User access the file and download it according to the Id given to the User

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-storage

I'm creating my first app using firebase, Myself as admin want to upload files with Pdf extension through web which I think using
Firebase storage is doable, and then I want to display it and make those files to be accessible inside android app,
I want the User of the app be able to download the Pdf files which is meant for the User. is this possible and if
this is possible, how would you approach it or how would you do it?

Thanks in advance

Comment: You might wanna see this - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37820471/firebase-limit-file-access-to-specific-users

Answer (score 0):

U can create folder with user:id in storage when save neded PDF